# can't override excel sheet with ExcelWriter / to_excel

Tags: python, pandas, overwrite

When I generate a new excel sheet, it works, but then when I run it again, the data is not overwritten. there is no error message.

```
pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
merge_df.to_excel(writer, startrow=0, sheet_name=line_sheet, index=False)
```

without ExcelWriter function, when I use only to_excel(excel_file), it works.
So I think the problem is in ExcelWriter.

Comment: And if you remove `mode='a'` ?

Comment: As @Timeless hinted, `mode='a'` is for appending, while the (default) `mode='w'` is for (over)writing. When you set `startrow=0` in combination with `mode='a'` you have conflicting settings.